# How to pass JSON values to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

**how to pass JSON values to array?**

i am making ajax request to get the json

```
$.getJSON( "data/data.json", function( data ) {         
        var obj=data["DataContainer"]["profit"];
        for(i in obj){
            var temp=[];
            temp.push(obj[i].current);
            temp.push(obj[i].target);
            data3.push(temp);
        }   
        JSON.stringify(data3).replace(/\"/g, "");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data3).replace(/\"/g, ""));
});
```

JSON

```
{
  "DataContainer": {
    "profit": [
      {
        "current": "60","target": "19"
      },
      {
        "current": "55","target": "19"
      },
      {
        "current": "55","target": "19"
      },
      {
        "current": "55","target": "19"
      },
      {
        "current": "55","target": "19"
      },
      {
        "current": "55","target": "19"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Console.log response will be

```
[[60,19],[55,19],[55,19],[55,19],[55,19],[55,19]]
```

Now i need to pass console.log values to

```
var rows = [["Current profit","Target profit"]],
            data3 = [[27, 19],[22,19],[35, 19],[23,19],[19, 19],[17,19]];
```

**My expected results**

```
var rows = [["Current profit","Target profit"]],
            data3 = [[60,19],[55,19],[55,19],[55,19],[55,19],[55,19]];
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks

For better understanding i have hosted my code in Jsfiddle ( i am not able to load the json from github)

please check this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/manjunath_siddappa/Yq3DW/61/)**

Comment: i'm not sure what you want, could you explain it a little bit more please?

Comment: i have a json file, i need to pass the values to array

json file Console.log response will be

[[60,19],[55,19],[55,19],[55,19],[55,19],[55,19]]

Now i need to pass console.log values to data 3
data3 = [[27, 19],[22,19],[35, 19],[23,19],[19, 19],[17,19]];

Comment: In the line: `JSON.stringify(data3).replace(/\"/g, "");` you create a string from the `data3` object, perform some regex replace, then immediately discard the results. Why? Might as well just put a comment there.

Comment: When you say "My expected results", you are giving two lines of code, which is not a result; could you clarify this ? What do you actually want to achieve ?

Comment: @ slebetman , can you please show me a sample code please

Comment: @  personne3000, i am working on c3.js

i need to change the values dynamically

var rows = [["Current profit","Target profit"]],
data3 = [[60,19],[55,19],[55,19],[55,19],[55,19],[55,19]];

in this code current and target profit are the labels and data 3 is the values which i want to pass to the c3.js

i have made the ajax request to get the json values now i need to pass these values to above data3 array, how can i achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want numbers instead of strings in `data3`, use `parseInt()`:

```
    for(i in obj){
        var temp=[];
        temp.push(parseInt(obj[i].current, 10));
        temp.push(parseInt(obj[i].target, 10));
        data3.push(temp);
    }
```

Comment: Removing the quotation marks around numbers in the JSON sent by the server would be better, if this is an option.

Comment: @ Barmar i tried above code it is not helping, please advice if any alternative way.

Comment: @ personne3000, i can remove the quotation marks from server code